# TSQL Abstraction of DB name and schema

Tags: database, t-sql, schema, abstraction

I've checked familiar posts and I hope that this hasn't been covered before.

I'm looking into ways to abstract the name of the DB and the schema in calling a stored procedure in a different database than the current location. Something in the following way:

execute [DatabaseName].[schema].[storedProcedureName]

The idea would be to allow the DB and the schema to be provided depending on a run time requirement. The obvious way to do this is to use dynamic sql but for the system I'm using thats a big no-no.  Does anyone know of anyway to abstract the DB name and schema in this case?  The only options I can think of are storing the name etc in variables and some how incorporating that into the execute call or being able to store an instance of the DB, but i don't know if thats even possible.

Any feedback will be useful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about abstracting it as you describe (like a parameter or something?), but one idea might be to do something like this:

```
IF @db = 'dababase1'
BEGIN
   IF @schema = 'schema1'
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE database1.schema1.procedure
   END
   IF @schema = 'schema2'
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE database1.schema2.procedure
   END
   ...
END
IF @db = 'database2'
BEGIN
...
```

You'd have to know at design time what all of the possible databases and schemas were though...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand the *why* behind this approach. What is calling your stored procedures? That might be the better place to change database by using a different connection string?

If you want to switch DB inside a TSQL statement then look at the [USE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188366%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) command and to run as a different user with access to another schema look at [EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181362%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're maybe looking for a construct like SYNONYM? This should allow that level of abstraction I believe

```
CREATE SYNONYM MySP FOR MyDatabase1.dbo.MySP
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/07/sql-server-2005-introduction-and-explanation-to-synonym-helpful-t-sql-feature-for-developer/